# implement mpc in simulink using matlab fmincon

Tags: matlab, optimization, controls, prediction

Hi I have a simulink model where I want to include a mpc controller for trajectory tracking of a robot.

I want to have the cost function J  = (r-x)^T*Q*(r-x) + u^T *R *u;

where
r is the reference states
x is the states
u is the control variables
Q and R are the penalty matrices

I want to avoid to make most of the algorithm without using inbuild matlab functions for learning purposes (meaning I want to avoid the nlmpc function to get an understand on how an mpc algorithm is build)

my problem is I don't know how to combine the predictor and the optimization. Should the predictor predict one step into the future and then go through the cost function or should the predictor predict the entire horizon and then insert all predictions in the cost function or how does it work?

for clarification I have this code I tried

```
for i = 1:N 
    x(i+1) = x(i) + Ts *x_dot; % Calculate the states in the next time step
```

(x_dot is a function of previous states and inputs)

(here is where I go wrong I don't know how to use the predictions in the fmincon should this be in the same loop or in another loop?)

Can someone help me with how to proceed?